# No puedo acceder a mysql mientras otro equipo está conectado

Tags: python, mysql, conexión

Tengo mysql XAMPP instalado en una Mac,  he compartido el acceso a la base de datos y logro conectarme con éxito desde otro equipo de la misma red. Tengo un programa en Python para gestionar los datos mysql instalado en varios equipos.  Sin embargo, cuando un equipo se conecta a la base de datos (usando la aplicación Python), los demás ya no pueden hacerlo.  Si cierro la aplicación Python en el primer equipo, ahí sí me permite que el segundo equipo se conecte y viceversa.
Está fallando alguna configuración de my.cnf ?  o es que estoy haciendo algo mal en mi programa Python que captura la conexión a mysql y no permite conexión desde otro equipo ?

Incluyo parte del archivo my.cnf:

```
[client]
#password       = your_password
port            =3306
socket          =/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysqld]
user=mysql
port=3306
socket          =/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
key_buffer=16M
max_allowed_packet=2M
table_open_cache=64
sort_buffer_size=512K
net_buffer_length=8K
read_buffer_size=256K
read_rnd_buffer_size=512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size=8M
bind-address=0.0.0.0
max_connections=500
wait_timeout=30
connect_timeout=10
```

Comment: Mi programa abre una conexión al iniciar la ejecución y mantiene abierta la conexión hasta que finaliza el programa, es decir, todas las consultas y actualización de la Base de Datos se hacen sobre una única conexión abierta al iniciar la aplicación. La conexión no se cierra nunca.  ¿Debería abrir y cerrar una nueva conexión cada vez que deseo realizar una consulta o una actualización?